# Button gets bigger at runtime as in designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a CustomButton-class and in Designer it looks fine. When I compile my project and watch my form at runtime the buttons are bigger then in designer.

In Designer it looks like this:

[image]

At Runtime it looks like this:

[image]

Here my CustomButton-class: (TPButton.cs)

```
public class TPButton : Button {
    public TPButton() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // TPButton
        // 
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 26);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

And here is my designercode from the view:

```
partial class EinAusschlussV {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.tpComboBox1 = new Infrastructure.CustomControls.TPComboBox();
        this.lblIln = new Infrastructure.CustomControls.TPLabel();
        this.tpButton1 = new Infrastructure.CustomControls.TPButton();
        this.tpButton2 = new Infrastructure.CustomControls.TPButton();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tpComboBox1
        // 
        this.tpComboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.tpComboBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.tpComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.tpComboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 11);
        this.tpComboBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
        this.tpComboBox1.Name = "tpComboBox1";
        this.tpComboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 25);
        this.tpComboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // lblIln
        // 
        this.lblIln.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblIln.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.lblIln.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 14);
        this.lblIln.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
        this.lblIln.Name = "lblIln";
        this.lblIln.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 17);
        this.lblIln.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblIln.Text = "ILN";
        // 
        // tpButton1
        // 
        this.tpButton1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.tpButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 10);
        this.tpButton1.Name = "tpButton1";
        this.tpButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
        this.tpButton1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tpButton1.Text = "tpButton1";
        this.tpButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // tpButton2
        // 
        this.tpButton2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.tpButton2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(172, 241);
        this.tpButton2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
        this.tpButton2.Name = "tpButton2";
        this.tpButton2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 26);
        this.tpButton2.TabIndex = 3;
        this.tpButton2.Text = "tpButton2";
        this.tpButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // EinAusschlussV
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(660, 497);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tpButton2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tpButton1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblIln);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tpComboBox1);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.Name = "EinAusschlussV";
        this.Text = "EinAusschlussV";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private TPComboBox tpComboBox1;
    private TPLabel lblIln;
    private TPButton tpButton1;
    private TPButton tpButton2;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You change the Button-Size in runtime in the InitializeComponent, thus overriding the values specified in the designercode.

Try the InitializeComponent without changeing the properties:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // TPButton
    // 
    this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    //this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
    //this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 26);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: I thought that would be for the designer. How can i set the default size for all TPButtons at design time?

Comment: Sry i found my Mistake. Thanks for yout help.

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier you should use [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and [Control.Dock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).